# A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type | .net core 6 vs .net framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

This piece of code is for `.net core 6` :

```
internal static string ConvertValueToString(this object value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case bool boolValue:
            return boolValue ? "true" : "false";

        case string stringValue:
            return stringValue;

        default:
            return value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to use it in `.net framework 4.8`.
In .net framework 4.8 i have 7 errors like below :

> A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string,
> integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

> Invalid expression term 'bool'

> Syntax error, ':' expected

> Invalid expression term 'string'

> Syntax error, ':' expected

> The name 'boolValue' does not exist in the current context

> The name 'stringValue' does not exist in the current context

How can i rewrite that method for .net framework 4.8?

---

I rewrote it like this :

```
if (value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
{
    bool boolValue = (bool)value;
    return boolValue ? "true" : "false";
}
else if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
{
    string stringValue = (string)value;
    return stringValue;
}
else
{
    return value?.ToString();
}
```

Is this correct?

---

Edit 2 :

```
//if (value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
if (value is string)
{
    bool boolValue = (bool)value;
    return boolValue ? "true" : "false";
}
//else if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
else if (value is bool)
{
    string stringValue = (string)value;
    return stringValue;
}
else
{
    return value?.ToString();
}
```

Is this correct too?

Comment: Compiles fine for me for .NET Framework 4.7.1. What language version you have set up for the project?

Comment: You could switch the Types fully qualified name instead, `switch (value.GetType().FullName)` and for cases use the fully qualified name string. ie. `case "System.Boolean":`

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 - .net framework 4.8 - c# language - class library.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: That works, but requires a good amount of type checking.  Since these types do not change, i think it would be safe to use the type name strings.  If you prefer the strongly typed version, that is fine too.

Comment: No need for `GetType` use `is`: `if(value is string)...`

Comment: @hijinxbassist please put your comment as answer - mean using `type name strings`.

Comment: That feature with the `switch` statement is a feature of the C# version, not the .NET version. I think it was introduced in C# 8.0.

Comment: Why is that entire code block not just compressed down to `x?.ToString()` ? You don't need to examine an object to find it to be a bool to convert it to a bool to ask if it's true or false to return "true"'or "false", you can just Tostirng a bool boxed as object to reveal a bool string eg `object o = true; return o.ToString();` it (is the PascalCase really a showstopper?)

Comment: @Guru Stron thanks for the comment and help - Please see my Edit 2

Comment: @Caius Jard you are right - i think `x?.ToString()` is enough for that method. I am just rewriting it for .net 4.8.

Comment: I think the original code has an a bit of a OO design problem (making decisions on the parameter type; not to mention scaling issues; also cyclomatic complexity) that given this opportunity might be a good time to re-write it.  Rather than `ConvertValueToString` to perform the conversion by making decisions,  simply call `value.ToString()` (which works with value types like bool).  You could even cut out the middle-man and have callers call `ToString()` directly now that `ConvertValueToString` isn't doing much.  Also check out `IFormattable`

Comment: is `return value?.ToString();` ok for that method? and should i remove extar codes?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I would say this is pattern matching (introduced in [C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching#switch-statement)) in switch statements (which were present for quite some time) and not [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) introduced in C# 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fully qualified names as cases and get the fully qualified name from the Type of the value.

```
var typeName = value.GetType().FullName;

switch (typeName)
{
    case "System.Boolean":
        // Do some boolean stuff
    break;
    case "System.String":
        // Do some string stuff
    break;
    default:
       // Unexpected type name
    break;
}
```

Since these types will never change, it is safe to use the string name for comparison.

Comment: Well, to many "magic" strings for me, compared to if else if construct with type check. Only makes sence for performance optimization, when you realy need hashcode performance (switch).

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly the cleanest way to do this at the moment:

```
internal static string ConvertValueToString(this object value)
{
    if (value is bool boolValue)
    {
        return boolValue ? "true" : "false";
    }
    else if (value is string stringValue)
    {
        return stringValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the value being cast and populating the new variable name in one line??  I am used to using `var myType = myObject as MyType;  if (myType != null)...`  Does this streamline that whole process?  Or does this work only on the value types (and string)?

Comment: @hijinxbassist - This works with any type. `variable is X x`. It works for any `X`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the answer - But these codes have error in my c# version.

Comment: @SilverLight - I've added two more answers with alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is to use a `List<(Type type, Delegate convert)>` to build your own version of a `switch`/`case` statement.

```
private List<(Type type, Delegate convert)> _register
    = new List<(Type type, Delegate convert)>();

public void Case<T>(Func<T, string> convert)
{
    _register.Add((typeof(T), convert));
}

public string Switch<T>(T value)
{
    Func<T, string> convert =
        _register
            .Where(x => x.type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            .Select(x => (Func<T, string>)x.convert)
            .Append(x => x?.ToString())
            .FirstOrDefault();
    
    return convert(value);
}
```

This can now be used like this:

```
Case<bool>(x => x ? "true!" : "false!");
Case<string>(x => $"!{x}!");
Console.WriteLine(Switch(true));
Console.WriteLine(Switch("Hello"));
```

That code writes out:

```
true!
!Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to use some extension methods:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static (object value, string output) Case<T>(this object value, Func<T, string> convert)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()) ? (value, convert((T)value)) : (value, null);
    }

    public static (object value, string output) Case<T>(this (object value, string output) source, Func<T, string> convert)
    {
        return source.output == null ? source.value.Case<T>(convert) : source;
    }

    public static string Switch(this (object value, string output) source)
    {
        return source.output == null ? source.value?.ToString() : source.output;
    }
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
var result1 =
    true
        .Case<bool>(x => x ? "true!" : "false!")
        .Case<string>(x => $"!{x}!")
        .Switch();

var result2 =
    "Hello"
        .Case<bool>(x => x ? "true!" : "false!")
        .Case<string>(x => $"!{x}!")
        .Switch();

Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Again this outputs:

```
true!
!Hello!
```